# How to create PRIMARY KEY in VIEW that uses OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-database-first, sql-view

I have created view that must use `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

I want to use this view in `EDMX` with DbFirst approach.

But the `EDMX` is generating next warning:

`<!--Errors Found During Generation:
warning 6013: The table/view 'MyView' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.`

I tried to solve this by adding 


`CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_MyView ON [dbo].[MyView] (Id)`

But Sql says:

`Cannot create index on view "dbo.MyView" because it uses a LEFT, RIGHT, or FULL OUTER join, and no OUTER joins are allowed in indexed views. Consider using an INNER join instead.`

Is there a way to add view without PK to edmx or add PK to the view.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an Indexed View and there are restrictions on the type of joins you can do in an Indexed view. Mainly, you can only perform an inner join. All other types of joins are not allowed.

There is a work-around to this limitation, which you can read about [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/indexedviewswithouterjoins/1884/) to see if it's appropriate in your situation. It's not a particularly attractive work-around though.

You generally don't need to index views unless you intend to use the indexed view to aggregate data, which is what indexed views are primarily useful for. Otherwise, having the appropriate indexes on the base tables should eliminate the need for an indexed view.

Comment: I need to index view because Entity Framework needs it. By index I mean index as prinary key.